# How to add a string at the end of another string which contains paragraphs, just before the last paragraph ends?

Tags: php

I have a string which contains multiple paragraphs:

```
$string  = '<p>I am the firt para.</p><p>I am a second para</p>';   

$more = '<a href="#">more</a>';
```

How can I add the **$more** string inside **$string**, just before the last paragraph ends, and get something like this:

```
$string = '<p>I am the firt para.</p><p>I am a second para <a href="#">more</a></p>';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: will $string always end with '</p>' ?

Comment: then i would use substr() to strip it then simply append the new string and add the close paragraph back

Comment: substring,,, it's been a while since I coded in php... I thought about regex'es, callbacks -- let me take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my initial idea

```
<?php
$string  = '<p>I am the firt para.</p><p>I am a second para</p>';   

$more = ' <a href="#">more</a></p>';


$new=substr($string, 0, -4);
$done=$new.$more;

echo $done; // <p>I am the firt para.</p><p>I am a second para <a href="#">more</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos = strrpos($string, "</p>");     //find last entrance of "</p>"
$string = substr($string, 0, $pos) . $more . substr($string, $pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it with regex, it might look like this:

```
$string  = '<p>I am the firt para.</p><p>I am a second para</p>';   
$more = '<a href="#">more</a>';
echo preg_replace('|</p>$|im', $more.'</p>', $string);
```

Test it online here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54bcaf41afe037fc9b5b75d869242378b257db4e

The regex uses a `$` to match against the end of the string. The `i` flag makes it case insensitive in case someone's got a capital `</P>`, `m` flag is for multiline.

Edit: Just want to note that this is probably the slowest method - it's much faster to use the `str*` functions in the other answers.